# Why does text copied from a set of pre tags have double line-breaks?

Tags: html, css, copy-paste, pre

I'm writing a small library to render Git diffs in a side-by-side format, in HTML. As one would expect, the left panel represents the previous commit and the right panel represents the current one.

I'd like for either panel to be able to use the browser's copy and paste facilities, so the user can grab the data within. I have found that the way I have arranged my HTML, at least in Firefox/Ubuntu, results in pasted output having two line breaks at the end of every line, rather than zero or one as I would have expected.

This is a snippet of code presentation from my renderer:

```
                <div class="line diff-line ">
                    <pre> */</pre>
                </div>
                <div class="line diff-line ">
                    <pre>function deletePost(PDO $pdo, $postId)</pre>
                </div>
                <div class="line diff-line ">
                    <pre>{</pre>
                </div>
                <div class="line diff-line diff-line-added">
                    <pre>   $sqls = array(</pre>
                </div>
                <div class="line diff-line diff-line-added">
                    <pre>       // Delete comments first, to remove the foreign key objection</pre>
                </div>
                <div class="line diff-line diff-line-added">
                    <pre>       &quot;DELETE FROM</pre>
                </div>
                <div class="line diff-line diff-line-added">
                    <pre>           comment</pre>
                </div>
                <div class="line diff-line diff-line-added">
                    <pre>       WHERE</pre>
                </div>
                <div class="line diff-line diff-line-added">
                    <pre>           post_id = :id&quot;,</pre>
                </div>
                <div class="line diff-line diff-line-added">
                    <pre>       // Now we can delete the post</pre>
                </div>
```

The `<div>` blocks are a red herring, it turns out - if they are stripped, the same behaviour is encountered with this:

```
                    <pre> */</pre>
                    <pre>function deletePost(PDO $pdo, $postId)</pre>
                    <pre>{</pre>
                    <pre>   $sqls = array(</pre>
                    <pre>       // Delete comments first, to remove the foreign key objection</pre>
                    <pre>       &quot;DELETE FROM</pre>
                    <pre>           comment</pre>
                    <pre>       WHERE</pre>
                    <pre>           post_id = :id&quot;,</pre>
                    <pre>       // Now we can delete the post</pre>
```

(I don't propose to take the `<div>`s out of the end solution - I'm taking them out here as I believe they are not the source of the problem).

Now, I suspect one fix is to have one set of `<pre>` tags wrapping everything, and to be careful about whitespace outside of the diff being presented. However, having arranged things as I have, I wonder if there is a CSS setting I can put on the `<pre>` tags to prevent them adding in blank lines that don't belong there?

I'm rather perplexed by this behaviour anyway - since they are block level I can understand why they would generate one NL on the end, but two is rather odd.

[There's an illustrative Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VXN4A/1/).

Comment: What editor are you pasting the text. I just tried mine and it looks ok. I dont get the 2 break lines

Comment: *prevent them adding in blank lines that don't belong there?* - The browser is going to render what's there, so there's something nonsensical about this.

Comment: I just inspected the fiddle with Chrome. Each line has 16 pixels height, i don't see any extra blank lines added. Are you on firefox?

Comment: I'm not getting any extra lines with your fiddle, but I don't know what text editor I'm supposed to use? (I tried jsfiddle's, SO answer, and notepad.)

Comment: I am on Firefox, yes. For the avoidance of doubt, I am selecting the text in the browser, and pasting into an external application (e.g. gedit, the JS panel in JS Fiddle, but it could be anything).

Comment: gedit has an auto indentation feature go to Edit->Preferences->Editor->3rd line  -- can you try that and see if it makes any difference

Comment: I can reproduce it on Firefox Windows (Chrome works fine). In fact, all you need to reproduce it is to save the basic HTML structure into an HTML file: `<pre>X</pre><pre>Y</pre>`

Comment: Thanks @Tasos, but that's switched off already - and the problem is also exhibited by pasting into JS Fiddle's spare (JS) editor panel.

Comment: Mozilla bug tracker is full of bug reports about this but they all show up as fixed. Weird...

Comment: Ok what about adding a block to the pre in CSS (pre {
    
   display:block;
    
}) .. can you try that

Comment: Ah thanks @Álvaro - if it looks like an acknowledged bug, then I could just provide a workaround. There might be something I can do in JS too, [perhaps like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/159582/472495).

Comment: @Tasos, good idea. In fact in my research I've seen reports of block-level things being helped by this (an iframe I think it was). Will give it a go...

Comment: you cant try margin and padding too -- (pre {
    
   display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    
}) -- may be that will do it

Comment: Well the pre is rendered as a block anyway in other browsers but maybe firefox is not picking that up and renders it incorectly

Comment: You can also use the (code) tag instead of the pre

Comment: @Tasos, resetting that CSS didn't seem to do anything. It's something that I think can easily be missed whilst testing a browser - after all, the rendering itself is fine. It's just how the data is being stored, +or+ how it is being transferred to the clipboard. It's interesting that it happens on Windows too, suggesting that it is not Linux-specific.

Comment: Well try the (code) tag to see if that helps. .

Comment: @Tasos, I think I tried `<code>` tags, and there was a problem with it, can't remember what it was. Not a bad idea though, I will try that again.

Comment: This is just what block elements do, so yes, wrap the whole thing in a `<pre>` and wrap each line with a `<span>`. I think GitHub uses a table, by the way, which seems to work.

Comment: @minitech, Álvaro says it works correctly in Chrome, so it doesn't sound just like a block-level effect. But yes, I should think one `<pre>` would sort it. Thanks for the GH tip - interesting. Some fixin' is required `:)`.

Comment: @halfer: I meant it was a block-level effect in Firefox, but it’s actually not quite. Hmm.

Comment: @minitech, it's an odd one. I've just switched out the set of `<pre>` tags for `<div>` tags with a preformatted `whitespace` class, and the double-CR effect is not exhibited.

Answer (score 1):

I installed this add-on for fire fox to copy the text as plain-text. This fixed the copying and pasting issue. So it sounds like to me the problem is that fire fox is copying some kind of formatting.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/copy-plain-text-2/developers

```
 pre {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bp4m6baq/2/

and use the add-on, and only then it works.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately, that adds another problem. Now the intentional line breaks are removed, and when copying and pasting the double-CRs are still there. I think it's a longstanding bug in FF.

Comment: Yes, I imagine a plugin would fix it, but that's no good for my website's users. I fixed it by removing the `<pre>` entirely, and using `white-space: pre` on `<code>` instead. (One of the commenters under the original post suggests that Github was driven to using tables for code formatting, so maybe they encountered the same issue!)